# Why do we OR || any condition with true like "iw dev interface_name del || true" in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Why would any expression in a bash script be ORed with `true`?

```
iw dev interface del || true
```

Answer (score 13):

The command probably occurs in the context of a script using `set -e`, which will cause the script to exit if any command has a non-zero exit status. If you run `iw dev interface del` and it fails, the script will exit. If you run `iw dev interface del || true`, though, even if `iw` fails, then `true` will run and it is *guaranteed* to succeed, meaning the exit status of the full command is zero.

Essentially, `<command> || true` is an idiom that means "Run <command> but ignore its exit status".